# Firewall was off, but TCPClient still throw error( a connection attempt failed ...)

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

Before post on this question, i already explore on this. But my problem was still happening.

TCPClient was throwing error even thought Firewall settings was OFF. Kindly see below on error details.

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond

When i checking with [TCP port checker](http://www.infobyip.com/tcpportchecker.php) the **specific website/IP and port was  Successfully connected**. But my environment was still throwing error.

Let me know how can i achieve on this? Thanks.

I just use sample Tcpclient code. Kindly see below.

```
Tcpclient client = new Tcpclient("www.example.com", 443);
```

Comment: Post the code for your client and server

Comment: i added code. Thanks.

Comment: Try it first using "www.google.com:443". If that also not working, then you have somewhere still firewall.

Comment: yes it still fail. what firewall setting i need to checked it? But i already off the firewall setting.

Answer (score 0):

for me,i stopped the firewall and still cannot use tcp,but when i added my app to inbound and outbound rules on firewall advanced sittings every thing is fine,and you can add it programmatically, i hope it is help full.

Comment: thanks you for your answer . . . i'll check it and get back to you . . .